# GoogleDrive API V3 in Browser: exposed Client ID and API Key. Any security issue?

Tags: security, google-drive-api, frontend

I'm trying to develop a Webapp that would allow users authenticate with their Google Account and store some information and files on their Google Drive.

It would be a static html/js page with no backend.

There is a quickstart example here:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js

It works fine but I am wondering if exposing my Client ID and API Key to everybody like in this example could not be a security problem. Anyone could use these id and key in their own app.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Changes to the Google APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.googleblog.com/2014/11/subject-changes-to-google-apis-terms-of.html), you are asked to keep your private keys private.

> Asking developers to make reasonable efforts to keep their private
>   keys private and not embed them in open source projects.

The author of that post was contacted and the exchange was made available on [DaImTo's blog](https://www.daimto.com/changes-to-the-google-apis-terms-of-service/). This is a part of the reply:

> Yes, you are not making your personal data available to them. You are,
>   however, allowing them to “impersonate” you in Google’s eyes. If our
>   abuse systems detect abuse (say, should someone try to DoS one of our
>   services using your key), you run the risk that they would terminate
>   your account because of it (and please note — they wouldn’t just cut
>   access to the key, they would shut down your console account).

Comment: Thanks. But then, shouldn't they warn developers of the risk in their example: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js